# How to detect a function and then fulfill conditional to remove html element by using javascript

Tags: javascript

One more time I need your help. I've used star wars intro and to display it I created buttons. It is played in popup div, but the footer makes height of container too big in for me so I want to remove this element when the code of star wars is displayed.

```js
//start music
     function play(){
       var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
       audio.play();
                 }
                 //stop music
     function stop(){
       var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
        audio.pause();
    audio.currentTime = 0;
                 }


//sekwenscja star wars 
  var sWidth; //screen width
var sHeight; //screen height
var canvas;
var context;
var numOfStars;
var starDensity = 1800; //lower == more stars
var starColors = ["#111", "#333", "#555", "#7872a8", "#483f26"];
var audio = $('audio').get(0);

$(document).ready(function() {
  
  //Play the theme song
  setTimeout(function() {
    audio.play();
  }, 7600);
  
  //Get the window size
  sWidth = $(window).width();
  sHeight = $(window).height();
  
  //Get the canvas
  canvas = $('#starfield');
  
  //Fill out the canvas
  canvas.attr('height', sHeight);
  canvas.attr('width', sWidth);
  context = canvas[0].getContext('2d');
  
  //Calculate the number of stars
  numOfStars = Math.floor((sWidth * sHeight) / starDensity);
  console.log(numOfStars);
  
  //Draw the stars
  function stars() {
    for (i=0;i<numOfStars;i++) {
      //Get a random star color
      var starColor = starColors[Math.floor(Math.random()*5)];
      //Get a random x-position
      var starX = Math.floor(Math.random()*sWidth);
      //Get a random y-position
      var starY = Math.floor(Math.random()*sHeight);
      //Draw
      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(starX, starY, 1, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      context.fillStyle = starColor;
      context.fill();
    }
  }
  
  //Draw the stars
  stars();
  
});
```

```css
.white_content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    z-index:1002;
    overflow: auto;
}



div#glowne {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1920px;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 1080px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  overflow: hidden;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1600px) {
  body {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}

/* In case of no audio support */
audio {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

#starfield {
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  animation: starfield 0s 8s forwards;
}

@keyframes starfield {
  to { opacity: 1; }
}

.long-time {
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  color: #00d7ff;
  top: 50%;
  left: 51%;
  width: 65%;
  transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
  font-size: 30px;
  font-size: 4.5vw;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  animation: long-time 5s 1s forwards;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1600px) {
  .long-time {
    font-size: 5.0em;
  }
}

@keyframes long-time {
  0% { opacity: 0; }
  18% { opacity: 1; }
  82% { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}

.logo {
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 3;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
  animation: logo 10s 8s cubic-bezier(0,.1,.2,1); forwards;
}

@keyframes logo {
  0% { opacity: 1; }
  98% { opacity: 1; }
  100% { width: 40px;
         opacity: 0; }
}

.crawl-container {
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 350vh;
  max-height: 3000px;
  /**/color: #ffe029;
  /**/text-align: justify;
  /**/overflow: hidden;
  /**/transform-origin: 50% 100%;/**/
  /**/transform: perspective(200px) rotateX(16deg);
  /**/animation: crawl-container 0s 17s forwards;
}

@keyframes crawl-container {
  to { opacity: 1; }
}

.crawl-container .crawl {
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%; /*skąd zaczyna przewijany tekst historii wypływać*/
  width: 100%;
  animation: crawl 170s 17s linear forwards;
}

.crawl p {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 0 10%;
  max-width: 1500px;
}

.crawl p.title {
  font-size: 3em;
  font-size: 5vw;
  text-align: center;
}

.crawl p.title-1 {
  margin-bottom: .7em;
}

.crawl p.title-2 {
  margin-bottom: 1.2em;
}

.crawl p.title-2 img {
  width: 65%;
  height: auto;
}

p.crawl-p {
  text-align: justify;
  font-size: 5.6vw;
  margin-bottom: 1.2em;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1600px) {
  p.crawl-p {
    font-size: 5.0em;
  }
}

@keyframes crawl {
  to { top: -250%; }
}
```

```html
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
 <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
 
  


<a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'"><input type="button" value="WEJDŹ"  onclick="play()">
<audio id="audio" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/331813/sw-7-theme.ogg" type="audio/ogg"></audio></a>
        <div id="light" class="white_content"> 
<div id="glowne">
        <audio preload="auto">
  <source src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/331813/sw-7-theme.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/331813/sw-7-theme.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
<canvas id="starfield"></canvas>
 <div class="long-time">A long time ago in a galaxy far,<br />far away....</div>
<img class="logo" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/331813/star-wars-7-logo.png" />
<div class="crawl-container">
  <div class="crawl">
      <p class="title title-1">Episode VII</p>
      <p class="title title-2"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/331813/the-force-awakens.png"></p>
      <p class="crawl-p">Luke Skywalker has vanished. In his absence, the sinister FIRST ORDER has risen from the ashes of the Empire and will not rest until Skywalker, the last Jedi, has been destroyed.</p>
      <p class="crawl-p">With the support of the REPUBLIC, General Leia Organa leads a brave RESISTANCE. She is desperate to find her brother Luke and gain his help in restoring peace and justice to the galaxy.</p>
      <p class="crawl-p">Leia has sent her most daring pilot on a secret mission to Jakku, where an old ally has discovered a clue to Luke's whereabouts....</p>
  </div>
</div></div><a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'"><input type="button" value="ZAKOŃCZ"  onclick="stop()"></a></div>
        <div id="fade" class="black_overlay"></div>


 
 <?php
  // Start the loop.
  while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

   // Include the page content template.
   get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'page' );

   // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
   if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) {
    comments_template();
   }

   // End of the loop.
  endwhile;
  ?>


 </main><!-- .site-main -->

 <?php get_sidebar( 'content-bottom' ); ?>

</div><!-- .content-area -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Euh, what is exactly the issue? If you want to remove an element, just select it and display: none or remove it altogether. You can put that code in where you start the music, or where you draw the stars. (eg, when this thingy starts.)

Comment: You have to forgive me but I'm not good at Javascript. I want to remove my footer only when I open popoup div and save it in normal view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to hide the footer

```
document.getElementById('footerID').style.display='none';
```

Comment: Thanks, you resolved my problem :)  As I said I'm not good at Javascript but I'm trying to be and with help of such a people like you it will be much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the HTML for your footer it is impossible to be exact, but you can simply hide it within the ready function:

```
$( /* unique selector for your footer */ ).hide();
```

I'd probably put this at the start of the ready function, but looking at your code the specific place you call should be pretty irrelevant.

P.S.

You could also call `$( /* ...footer */ ).remove();`, but hiding it will allow you to show it again should the need arise.

Comment: <footer id="colophon" class="site-footer" role="contentinfo">                         
   <ul id="footermenu"> <!-- Pasek menu w stopce -->
   <li>Menu</li>
   <li><a href="http://localhost/">Aktualności</a></li>
   <li><a href="http://localhost/index.php/strazacy-7/">Strażacy</a></li></ul></footer> It would like this, for example.

Comment: Your are great, thanks for help. The problem is resolved  :)